# IntelliJ equivalent of "Inclusion and Exclusion Patterns"?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have an Eclipse project where the Java build path is defined (in the project properties) to contain the folder "src" with certain inclusion patterns ("com/example/package1/**", "com/example/package3/**"). The reason is that, say, "package2" contains things that are irrelevant to this project but are relevant to some other project that shares its source tree.

I would like to try to use IntelliJ IDEA, but I can't seem to find the equivalent feature. Does it exist, or is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Under a content root you can

-Include source folders (The folders containing the com package) with the blue folder button.

-Exclude folders with the red folder button. It will completely remove files from the intellij eyes. Not just to the java compiler.

-If this is not enough you have /setting/compiler/exclude where you can exclude packages or files individually but only to the compiler eyes. You can quickly add a file to these excludes by right clicking on a java compilation error. It may also work for compilers other than the java one.

Comment: That does not really answer the question. It is ok for a few directories — but if you have 10 or ´.backup´ directories to exclude it becomes painful. — More so as InteliJ *forgets* that particular set-up quite often. — The OP asked for patter exclude and so do I.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Structure window, under the Modules section, Sources tab,  you can mark some directories as "excluded" by selecting it and clicking on the "red folder" button.

Comment: No, I think it works on IDEA 10 as well; however, I'd really prefer to use inclusion rather than exclusion patterns; also, I could conceivably need file-level granularity, which this does not provide.

Comment: true (all your statements). A solution may be to define multiple content roots, but it will depend on your directory layout. Anyway, this would be a nice feature for IDEA.. time to go to the EAP and log a feature request :)

Comment: Again, that does not really answer the question. See my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Preferences…/File Types/Ignored files and folders

This applies to all projects though.